# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am getting above error when i try to show id in pop up window.

my code are below

grid.cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/Grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="login_for_review" class="modal hide" role="dialog"></div>
```

grid.js

```
var init = function () {
    var Grid = $("#Grid");
    Grid.kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if (type == "read") {
                        return {
                            limit: ,
                            offset: ,
                            sort: 
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Records",
                total: "TotalRecordCount" 
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 25,
            serverSorting: true,
            sort: { field: "Name", dir: "asc" }
        },          
        sortable: {
            allowUnsort: false
        },
        pageable: true,
        pageable: {
            pageSizes: 
        },
        noRecords: {
            template: ""
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Name",
                title: "Name"
            },
            {
                template: "<div>#if(data.id> 0){#<a href = 'javascript:void(0);' onClick='showDiv(#:TemplateId#)'>#:id# Sites</a>#} else{#ff#}#</div>",
                field: "id",
                title: ""
            }
        ]
    });
};

(function ($) {
    $(document).trigger("o", [false, { type: "item", href: "url", text: "", showText: true }]);
    init();
})(jQuery);

function showDiv(data) {
    getSiteId();
    console.log(data);
}

var getSiteId = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#login_for_review').html(data).modal('show');
           // window.$('#myModal').modal();
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
};
```

actually I am trying to show return id like 1,2,3.. in horizonal in a pop up    when showDiv clicked .
I have followed some links and implemented in this way . Could you please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: I don't think  `.modal()` is a native jQuery method, you might be missing a plugin for it

Comment: is there any other way to show pop up . and i can confirm in exiting code .model(); in use.